# ecSignHashAsync() giving INVALID_SIGNATURE Error

Tags: web3js, decentralized-exchange, 0x

I'm trying to create an order in 0x but when I try to sign the order I get `INVALID_SIGNATURE` error?

I'm using 0x version 2

```
onSubmit = async (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();

    const { makerAmount, takerAmount, makerToken, takerToken, maker } = this.state;
    const contractAddresses = getContractAddressesForNetworkOrThrow(KOVAN_NETWORK_ID);
    const zrxTokenAddress = contractAddresses.zrxToken;
    const etherTokenAddress = contractAddresses.etherToken
    const contractWrappers = new ContractWrappers(web3Wrapper._provider, { networkId: KOVAN_NETWORK_ID });

    const makerZRXApprovalTxHash = await contractWrappers.erc20Token.setUnlimitedProxyAllowanceAsync(
        zrxTokenAddress,
        maker,
    );

    const makerAssetAmount = Web3Wrapper.toBaseUnitAmount(new BigNumber(makerAmount), DECIMALS);

    // the amount the maker wants of taker asset
    const takerAssetAmount = Web3Wrapper.toBaseUnitAmount(new BigNumber(takerAmount), DECIMALS);

    // 0x v2 uses hex encoded asset data strings to encode all the information needed to identify an asset
    const makerAssetData = assetDataUtils.encodeERC20AssetData(zrxTokenAddress);
    const takerAssetData = assetDataUtils.encodeERC20AssetData(etherTokenAddress);

    // Set up the Order and fill it
    const randomExpiration = getRandomFutureDateInSeconds();
    const exchangeAddress = contractAddresses.exchange;

    // Create the order
    const order = {
        exchangeAddress,
        makerAddress: maker,
        takerAddress: NULL_ADDRESS,
        senderAddress: NULL_ADDRESS,
        feeRecipientAddress: NULL_ADDRESS,
        expirationTimeSeconds: randomExpiration,
        salt: generatePseudoRandomSalt(),
        makerAssetAmount,
        takerAssetAmount,
        makerAssetData,
        takerAssetData,
        makerFee: ZERO,
        takerFee: ZERO,
    };

    // Generate the order hash and sign it
    const orderHashHex = orderHashUtils.getOrderHashHex(order);

    console.log(orderHashHex);
    console.log(maker);
    console.log(web3Wrapper._provider);

    const signature = await signatureUtils.ecSignHashAsync(web3Wrapper._provider, orderHashHex, maker);
    const signedOrder = { ...order, signature };

    const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
    const session = driver.session();
    await session.run(
        'CREATE (a:Order {id:$id, maker:$maker, makerAmount: $makerAmount, takerAmount:$takerAmount, makerToken:$makerToken, takerToken:$takerToken})',
        { id: uuidv1(), maker: maker, makerAmount: makerAmount, takerAmount: takerAmount, makerToken: makerToken, takerToken: takerToken, signedOrder: signedOrder }
    );
    session.close();
    this.setState({ errorMessage: '', makerAmount: 0, takerAmount: 0, makerToken: 'zrx', takerToken: 'weth' });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with 0x provider I should be used MetamaskSubprovider instead of signerprovider